# What is this red flowering plant in the background shown in one of the episodes of "better call saul"?

Tags: identification

To me, it kinda looks like a climbing rose but i dont see a trellis supporting the vine so it might aswell be a shrub of some kind. Any clue? [image][image][image]

Comment: Hard to say without a close up but I would guess they are roses.

Comment: Agree, most likely a rose - it might be supported by wires on the wall, which obviously aren't visible

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't contain photographs that are clear enough to identify the plant in question.

Comment: Agree with @NiallC. And considering that this is a film set, it may as well be some props, shaped to resemble *maybe a rose*.

Comment: The filming location for this series is Albuquerque, NM; confirmed by the overhead sun (see shade from sun lotion bottle), so dry tropical. Roses would be high maintenance, particularly against a wall, but certainly possible. An alternative might be Bougainvillea flower clusters, which come in this deep red. Here they are either regularly pruned or recently planted.

Comment: @Niall C_ believe me,  I couldnt get the picture any clearer then this because since the start of the scene besides the pool, the characters had been in sharp focus which led to eveything else being blurry due to the shallow depth of field.

Comment: @Colin Beckingham_ you got the name of the city right just by looking at the sunscreen and the position of the sun?? Are you serious?